# Set default value for select if `select` is inserted

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form with fields. If `RiskType` field is `ILI` and at the same time 'Limit Type' field is I or Y, then
The `Settlement` drop down list is inserted
my question is how to make the netSettlement variable set value the first option in select. If this form has been inserted in the DOM (logically, if the form is not inserted, the value is not set)

```js
    {(riskType === 'ILI' && (limitType === 'Y' || limitType === 'I')) &&
      <Form.Row>
        <Form.Group controlId='formGridNetSettlement'>
          <Form.Label>Settlement</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control name='netSettlement' as='select' value={netSettlement}
                        onChange={e => {setNetSettlement(e.currentTarget.value)} }
                        required={!isSearch}>
            <option>True</option>
            <option>False</option>
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form.Row>
    }
```

Comment: p.s. netSettlement is set to null at the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have values in options at all. If you're receiving Boolean value for `netSettlement` try this

```js
{
  riskType === "ILI" && (limitType === "Y" || limitType === "I") && (
    <Form.Row>
      <Form.Group controlId="formGridNetSettlement">
        <Form.Label>Settlement</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          name="netSettlement"
          as="select"
          value={netSettlement.toString()}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setNetSettlement(e.currentTarget.value);
          }}
          required={!isSearch}
        >
          <option value="true">True</option>
          <option value="false">False</option>
        </Form.Control>
      </Form.Group>
    </Form.Row>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yep I forgot to add value to the option and forgot to write, netSettlement has null at the beginning
(And we have problem with .toString())

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add the `selected` attribute to the option that you want pre-selected when the form is loaded:

```
<option selected value="true">True</option>
<option value="false">False</option>
```

Also, you will want to set the `value` attribute with the actual value you want to submit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how do I make a variable (netSettlement) have the value `option` by default ?